# Java Client Socket blocking on BufferedReader?

Tags: java, sockets, io, bufferedreader, printwriter

I am using old school `java.net.Socket`

My client connects to server and does:

```
BufferedReader in =
   new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
String fromServer = in.readLine();
```

It hangs at in.readLine().

My server accepts a connection from the client and does:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
out.print("Hello client\n");
```

My expectation would be that as soon as out.print("Hello client\n"); is invoked, the client should stop blocking and continue on.

What are my doing wrong?

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
BufferedReader in =
   new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
String fromServer = in.readLine();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are not calling `out.flush();` See [PrintWriter.flush](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#flush%28%29)

From [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.io.OutputStream,%20boolean%29)

> autoFlush - A boolean; if true, the println, printf, or format methods will flush the output buffer

So `Autoflush` will not work for `print` you will need to call `flush()` mannually

Comment: autoflush is set PrintWriter constructor.

Comment: Specifically, `autoFlush - A boolean; if true, the println, printf, or format methods will flush the output buffer`. This is quoted from the link that AmitD made in his post to PrintWriter.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `out.print("Hello client\n")`, which isn't autoflushed, when you should be calling `out.println("Hello client")`, which is autoflushed.